# Checkbox inside ListView custom adapter

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, custom-adapter

This is my custom_list.xml

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/cb"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:checked="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/nameTV"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:padding="16dp" />
```

and this is my CustomAdapter.java

```
private Context context;
private ArrayList<String> arrayList;
private CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener;
private boolean[] mItemChecked;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList, CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener) {
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.onCheckedChangeListener = onCheckedChangeListener;
    mItemChecked = new boolean[arrayList.size()];
    for (int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++){
        mItemChecked[i] = true;
    }
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    TextView tv;
    CheckBox cb;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return arrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return arrayList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

public boolean itemIsChecked(int position){
    return mItemChecked[position];
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
        holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.tv.setText(arrayList.get(position));
    holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(onCheckedChangeListener);
    return convertView;
}
```

While everything works fine, there is 1 problem: the checkboxes from rows 1, 2 ,3... is bound to the checkboxes from rows 8, 9, 10... so whenever I uncheck the checkbox 1, and scrolls down to checkbox 8, he's also unchecked, and vice versa.
I guess it is something related to the view holder which doesn't recycle the checkboxes correctly, and using for rows 1 and 8 the same checkbox. Any suggestions to overcome this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`convertView` in `getView` is previously used `View` with previous data! So you need to fill your `View` with correct data each time in `getView`. In your code I don't see where you set state of `checkbox`. You should do it. As you do for `TextView` `holder.tv.setText(arrayList.get(position));`

**Update**

Here is code sample. Take a look at `getView`. Other things like creation of initial data or data structure are simplified.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private List<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(30);
    private boolean[] mItemChecked = new boolean[30];
    private Context mContext;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            arrayList.add("text: " + i);
            mItemChecked[i] = false;
        }
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrayList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    public boolean itemIsChecked(int position) {
        return mItemChecked[position];
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.tv = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
            holder.cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cb);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tv.setText(arrayList.get(position));
        //Important to remove previous listener before calling setChecked
        holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(null);
        holder.cb.setChecked(mItemChecked[position]);
        holder.cb.setTag(position);
        holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(
                new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        mItemChecked[position] = isChecked;
                    }
                });
        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView tv;
        CheckBox cb;

    }
}
```

`ListView` recycles its view in the `getView()` method. Add these two methods to solve:

```
public int getViewTypeCount() {                 
    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Yap, that's what I though was the problem, I just couldn't find the right way to do it. Do you have an idea how can I get the right state of checkbox for each row even after the row scrolled away from the view?

Comment: @Bimba Added a code sample. Take a look at `getView`. Be aware, other things are simplified. You should yourself select appropriate data structures to store data.

Comment: Many Thanks bro, it did solve my problem, but another problem came with this... Now it doesn't save the checkboxes state whenever it is recycled. So if I check one of the checkboxes, than scrolling down, and than scrolling back up, it remains unchecked.

Comment: @Bimba just try the provided code. checkboxes state is saved in `mItemChecked` array.